# How to resize my 40G Ubuntu partition?

Tags: gparted, windows-10, partitioning

I re-partitioned my Windows 10 (1TB), installed along side Ubuntu  and allocated(40GB).

Now I would like to increase the size of my Ubuntu from 40GB => 200GB ?

FYI: Already installed gparted. Confused on what to do now.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHafb.png)

Comment: Use Windows tools to shrink the NTFS partition. While gparted often works, some have had issues. If you use Windows then any issues are Windows only. Reboot into Windows so it can run chkdsk which is required after any resize. Then use gparted. You can either move / , your sda6 left & expand right or probably better create new partition and use as /home. Be sure to have good backups before anything else. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: That seems kind impossible given your actual partition scheme. You would have to resize your windows partition and then *move* your linux partition, and the resize it... But you would surely end with a broken system.

Comment: First you'll need to create free space, i.e. shrink your windows partition. Then you can use that for Linux. I'd suggest doing the shrinking from within Windows and maybe not add the new space to your exiting partition but rather make it a separate home partition and move the old home there.

Comment: Boot from a Live USB - you cannot resize partitions when they're mounted (and booting from them mounts them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Windows and Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

This is a two part process. Resize the Windows NTFS partition, and move/resize the Ubuntu partition.

**In Windows...**

- temporarily disable the pagefile using the System control panel
- reboot
- defrag
- use the `Disk Management` app to resize the Windows NTFS C: partition
- open a `CMD` (command) terminal with admin privs
- issue a `chkdsk /f C:` and confirm to do this on next reboot
- reboot, observe `chkdsk` running
- reboot and confirm that Windows still boots
- re-enable the pagefile
- reboot and confirm that Windows still boots

**For Ubuntu...**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sda6 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sda6 all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- reboot

Comment: "Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Windows and Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data." Truer words were never said.